# In which universe was "Letters Of Transit" (season 4 ep 19) happening?

Tags: fringe

"Letters Of Transit" (season 4 ep 19) is a really odd episode. Previous episodes were following a story arc, and suddenly we step forward 20 years in the future and discard the current story. It's like it was a whole new series, but with the same characters.

Even more strange, the next episode preview show us the continuation of the season's story arc!

I'm really confused, what was happening? Was this a glimpse of a possible future or was it a complete new universe?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It took place Over Here.  They visited Massive Dynamic, a company that does not exist Over There.  Ergo, it must have been Over Here.

In addition, it's not just a hint of a possible future.  The show runners [recently revealed](http://www.tv.com/news/fringes-bosses-discuss-the-two-part-finale-and-season-5-28538/) we'll see that future again:

> What about the future scenario of 2036, as seen in "Letters of Transit," will we see that again? "Yes I think it's safe to say we will," said Wyman.

It's unclear if this means we'll be seeing it in the final 2 episodes of season 4, or if he's referring to season 5.

Comment: I understand that, By an "complete new universe" universe, I was more thinking about a third place, an Under-Here if you prefer.

Comment: @DavRob60 Oh I see.  I don't think there's any indication there's a 3rd universe as an option.  They've really stuck to their guns about the whole 'there are only 2 universes' thing.  Personally, I would have expected a 3rd universe by now.

Comment: btw, now that Season 5 has started, we know it's all of Season 5

Answer (score 1):

I was confused too but I think it was an alternate reality... So basically a reality in which the Observers stepped in.... because the observers travel through time techinically that reality Can Still Happen no matter how the "Jones Saga" Ends.. I'm guessing its a ploy to get Fox to give them At least one more season to answer that question..

Answer (score 1):

I think its a possible future, an one the series may end up going more towards, or at least have the fringe team aiming to to prevent that future. It was defo an odd episode though. I'm sure it ended in a way that would leave you assuming the story will continue further down the line. So it would be strange if it was just the one off episode an it was the end of that story. Season 5 might end up portraying the events that lead up to that future where the team are encased in amber etc.

Or maybe its a glimpse of what season 5 will primarily be about an the plot/story line that season will follow. Either way it leaves a lot of options for them to explore in season 5 an could possibly take the story in a new direction.

The fact Olivia is not in that episode an was killed by William Bell could also signal that maybe shes left the show an will not be in the next season (pure speculation), just seems odd to kill off one of the main characters just like that, an rather randomly too. Doesn't mean to say the other Olivia isn't still alive though, we never saw her or the other side at all.

Comment: The episode didn't say that Bell killed Olivia, just that he did something to her.  In addition her death isn't random, it's been foreshadowed since *Lysergic Acid Diethylamide*.